# How to use post method in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, post, postman, node-modules

I have a node js file in which

I am preforming sum of two numbers

using postman to send data and post method

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.post('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
var f = parseInt(req.body.f);
    console.log("hello" + f);
var l = parseInt(req.body.l);
  var sum = Number(f + l);
  res.send('The sum is: ' + Number(sum));
})
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

here I am sending the data `f` from postman

and `NaN` data error
here is my screenshort of postman from where I am sending data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVvNw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not parsing body data to `json` using `body parser`. use below snippet.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: what if I want to send them through form-data?

Comment: You can use multer for this. refer [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_form_data.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Can you log the req.body (`console.log(req.body)`) before using `parseInt(req.body.f)` and let us know what you get please?

I think it's something related to parsing.

Regards,

Comment: `{}` I have got this in my console when I did `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are sending using postman? Because it looks like you aren't sending the data in the body of the request.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the screenshort init

Comment: Ok I found the solution, you need to send them not as "form-data" in postman but as "x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
```

This has been deprecated I guess.
You can delete the line above, and change it like below, also add other line. If it works, please let us know.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json())
```